# The Magnetic Field Strength of Crab nebula

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, radiation, plasma-physics

Consider the spectrum of the Crab nebula shown below.

Assuming that the ~TeV photons are produced by Inverse Compton scattering of
synchrotron photons from around the peak of the synchrotron component of the spectrum, and that the Inverse Compton scattering is due to the same population of electrons as produces the peak of the synchrotron emission, how can we estimate the characteristic magnetic field strength by using the spectra below?

[image]

Comment: You estimate it from the synchrotron emission, which goes as $B^2$, not from the TeV emissions (generally assumed to be due to cosmic ray electrons or protons).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am still not sure how you can obtain it from the synchrotron emission - what do you mean when you say it goes as $B^2$?

Comment: Have you done even cursory search of "synchrotron radiation" in your favorite search engine? There's loads of resources that give definitions and derivations...

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation